# PHP - LDAP search working sporadically over TLS/SSL

Tags: php, linux, apache, ldap

The code below performs a lookup of all `OrganizationalUnits` in my LDAP server however it's failing to perform the LDAP search like 40% of the time.

The only clues I have are two Apache log entries below. I'm not a PHP wizard, but assuming the second error message is caused by the failed connection leaving an empty `$sr` variable.

I've run `tcpdump` during the connect and PHP *is* connecting to the server but there is very little communication going on during the failure -- only around 1/2 as many packets transferred as opposed to a successful connect.

This only seems to happen over TLS/SSL (hecnce the `putenv` last-ditch-effort). If I go clear-text the search works perfectly every time. What would cause this to not work "sometimes"? Any way to find out more info on it?

**Update:** I just noticed this code works 100% of the time when not using LDAPS/TLS so definitely related to SSL/TLS somehow.

```
<?php
   putenv('TLS_REQCERT=never');
   print "<html><head><title>ldap test</title></head><body>";

   $ldapconn = ldap_connect("ldaps://my.ldap.com") or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");
   ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

   if ($ldapconn)
   {
      $basedn = "dc=my,dc=ldap,dc=com";
      $attributes = array("ou","cn");
      $sr = ldap_search ($ldapconn, $basedn, "(ObjectClass=OrganizationalUnit)", $attributes);
      $info = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $sr);
   }

   if ($info["count"] > 0)
   {
      for ($i=0; $i < $info["count"]; $i++)
      {
         $ou = $info[$i]["ou"][0];
         print "<br><input type='radio' name='ldap_ou' value='$ou'>$ou<br>";
      }
   }

   print "</body></html>";

?>
```

Apache Errors:

```
PHP Warning:  ldap_search(): Search: Can't contact LDAP server in /var/www/test.php on line 14
PHP Warning:  ldap_get_entries() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/test.php on line 15
```

**Update 2** (debug fail info):

```
...
ldap_prepare_socket: 18
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying 10.14.13.92:636
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 18 tm: -1 async: 0
TLS: peer cert untrusted or revoked (0x42)
TLS: can't connect: (unknown error code).
ldap_err2string
....
```

Comment: tried ldap_error after the ldap_search ? http://php.net/manual/de/function.ldap-error.php

Comment: Is ldap working fine out of php? make sure that, may help https://serverfault.com/a/452940/322998

Comment: @FatFreddy - yeah, tried that straight away, all it says is `Success` after the `ldap_connect` (even when it fails) and `Can't contact LDAP server` after the search.

Comment: @DiogoAlves - yes, `ldapsearch -x -ZZ` works every time from the command line

Comment: Something I'd do on a copy of the code that's being run manually -- there are debug flags you can enable that make the error reporting more verbose (http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-set-option.php)

ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);

Run the script from a command line (php filename.php) and you'll see a LOT of output.

Comment: Strange. It runs from the CLI just fine (20/20 times). When in the browser (firefox anyway) it fails like 2/10 times. The debug info (found in apache error log) looks like some kind of SSL error (edited post) It's contacting the same ldap server, so don't know how it could be a cert issue.

Answer (score -1):

I am having the same problem. LDAP server wants TLS so we have to use ldaps to connect to the server. **ldap_connect** and **ldap_bind** works everytime. But following **ldap_search** fails sporadically with *Can't contact LDAP Server (-1)* error.

On LDAP side I can see a working bind request on my ldap server, but nothing more -.-

I am using CentOS with php7.2, does anybody had the same issues or any solution?

---

Okay, I switched to use http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-start-tls.php which solved the problem for me.